# why curve should be planar?

Tags: differential-geometry

Please explain to me why it is necessary to assume that the curve was planar?
If for a regular surface parametrized by $f$ we define the curvature in the direction of $X$ to be the curvature of a curve $c$ formed by intersecting the plane through $p$ and parallel with $\nu$ and $X$ with the surface, and $c'(0)=X$, where $X \in T_pf $ and each $X$ is a unit vector. That is $c$ is a planar curve spanned by $\nu$ and $X$.

Note: This question has been edited to follow the site regulations.
My attempt at solving this problem: Let $c$ be a parametrized curve on the surface, parametrized by arc length, that is $\langle c',c' \rangle =1$. and $ c(0)=p$. The total curvature $\kappa$ of $c$ at $p$ is equal to the length of $c''$. We decompose $c''$ into its tangential and normal components. Now, $c''(0) =c''(0)^{Tang.}+\langle c''(0), \nu \rangle \nu$ when $c$ is a planar curve in a plane parallel to $\nu (p)$. Since $c''(0)$ and $c'(0)$ are orthogonal, the tangential component of $c''(0)$ vanishes. this is not necessarily true if $c$ is non-planar. When  $c''(0)^{Tang.} \neq 0$, we have $\kappa=\Vert c''(0) \Vert > | \langle c''(0), \nu \rangle |= | II (c'(0),c'(0) | $.

Answer (score 1):

It's more accurate to say the planar hypothesis is *without loss of generality*: The normal curvature of a surface depends only on a point $p$ of the surface and direction $v$ at $p$.

Comment: But only for the normal plane slice is the normal curvature (up to sign) the actual curvature of the curve.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right, I should explicitly clarify that "depends only on..." means we're looking only at curves in the surface whose osculating plane is the normal plane to the surface, not arbitrary curves with the given position and velocity.